# I'm not able to create a hangouts link or google meet link through google calendar API

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-meet

A few days ago , it was working the "Automatically add Google Meet to my calendar events".
Suddenly, It has not worked in Google Calendar API and the "getHangoutLink()" returns "null".

How can I fix it? Help me with some codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
Event event = new Event()
        .setSummary(title)
        .setLocation(location)
        .setDescription(description);


DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime( date +"T"+startTime+"+06:00" );//"2020-05-05T11:00:00+06:00");
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
        .setDateTime(startDateTime)
        .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(date +"T"+endTime+"+06:00");//"2020-05-05T12:00:00+06:00");
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
        .setDateTime(endDateTime)
        .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
event.setEnd(end);

String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"};
event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));
```

/*  s1 = "abc@gmail.com";
s2 = "xyz@gmail.com";

```
EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
        new EventAttendee().setEmail(s1),
        new EventAttendee().setEmail(s2),
};*/



EventAttendee attendees[];

attendees = new EventAttendee[allAttendees.size()];

for(int i=0; i<allAttendees.size(); i++){
   // System.out.println(allAttendees.get(i));
    attendees[i] = new EventAttendee().setEmail(allAttendees.get(i));
}
event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));



EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
        new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
        new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};


Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
        .setUseDefault(false)
        .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);


ConferenceSolutionKey conferenceSKey = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
conferenceSKey.setType("hangoutsMeet"); // Non-G suite user
CreateConferenceRequest createConferenceReq = new CreateConferenceRequest();
createConferenceReq.setRequestId("3whatisup3"); // ID generated by you
createConferenceReq.setConferenceSolutionKey(conferenceSKey);
ConferenceData conferenceData = new ConferenceData();
conferenceData.setCreateRequest(createConferenceReq);
event.setConferenceData(conferenceData);

String calendarId = "primary";

try {
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).setConferenceDataVersion(1).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
System.out.printf("Hangout Link %s\n", event.getHangoutLink());
```